# Python with CouchDB 2.0

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python, couchdb-2.0

I have `CouchDB 2.0` server.
I need to create, delete, get, update and query the databases via python.

On `1.6` version there was a `couchdb-python` lib.
What is the best option here ? Work with the couchdb rest-api directly?

Comment: There are very minor changes between 1.6.1 and 2.0. Updating the library should not be that long

Comment: the 1.6 compatible lib should continue to work for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

You also have [python-cloudant] and [couchdbkit] as well as a python module named simply [couchdb](https://pypi.org/project/CouchDB/)  , which has recent updates in 2018.

Nice related gist: 
https://gist.github.com/marians/8e41fc817f04de7c4a70

Searching PyPI finds a lot https://pypi.org/search/?q=couchdb